# c++ char array output in class functions

Tags: c++, arrays, char, output, cout

I am a real c++ beginner and I have a problem with my char array output in a c++ excerise. I was asked to transform a certain UML class in to c++ and generate an working output with the parameters given in main. Here ist the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*My class defintion book*/

class Book
{   protected: 
        long int number; 
        char author[25];
        int year;
        bool lent;

        void setLent(bool x);
        bool getLent(); 
    public: 
        Book(long int n, char a[25], int j, bool x);
        long int getNr();
        int getYear();
        void print();
        };
/*Method definition Book*/
Book::Book(long int n, char a[25], int j, bool x)
    {number=n;
    author=a;
    year=j;
    lent=x;}

long int Book::getNr()
    {return number; }

int Book::getYear()
    {return year;}

void Book::setLent(bool x)
    {lent=x;}

bool Book::getLent()
    {return lent;}

void Book::print()
    {
    std::cout << "Book Nr: " << number << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Author: " << author << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Year: " << year << std::endl;
    if (lent==0)
    std::cout << "Lent [yes/no]: no" << std::endl;
    else
    std::cout << "Lent [yes/no]: yes" << std::endl;
    }

/*MAIN*/

int main()
{
Book b1(123456, "test", 2014, false);

b1.print();

system("pause");
return 0;
```

This is my output:

```
Book Nr: 123456
Author: b<Vv-[[vóYA
Year: 2014
Lent [yes/no]: no
Press any key to continue...
```

As you can see all outputs work except for the "Author". There I am getting crap. Note that I have to use char as type. since it is given in the UML class I had to transform into c++.

I really searched everywhere. But didn't find the correct solution. I have the feeling it will be a very simple one...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `author=a;` <-- this line in your constructor doesn't do what you think it does. Why aren't you using `std::string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that you're assigning your *pointer* `author` to another *pointer* `a`, which then goes out of scope... so you're left with `author` pointing to some garbage. If you want to stick with character arrays, you'll have to copy all the data that `a` points to:

```
strcpy(author, a);
```

But since it's C++, you should just use strings, which are easier to deal with:

```
class Book {
    ...
    std::string author;
    ....
};

Book::Book(long int n, const std::string& a, int j, bool x)
: author(a), ...
{ }
```

Comment: Oh it's an array? How does that even compile then?

Comment: @Barry: You should better use `strncpy(author, a, 25);` - and my g++ (version: (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5) didn't compile the original code from the questioner:  `original.cpp:25: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [25]’`

Comment: @StefanK. yeah that error is what I'd expect (and get on gcc 4.7.3). And I disagree on strncpy, especially if you're telling it to copy 15 more bytes than author can hold!

Comment: Fixed the posting. It's 00:35 am here... don't know where this wrong number came from. ;-)

Comment: Hm, should I put that `Book book666(666, "Satan overwrites your stack with 666 666 666 666 666 666.... Muhahaha!", 2014, false);` into your library?

Comment: You are all right about your comments concerning strubf. I already knew/read about the problems with char. Unfortunately, I have to use it as it is required by the UML class. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out uninitialized data.

Make author a string

```
#include <string>
class Book
{   protected: 
        long int number; 
        std::string author;
        int year;
        bool lent;
```

and make the argument to the constructor a string as well

```
Book::Book(long int n, const std::string& a, int j, bool x)
```

Arrays of characters are not as flexible as std::strings.  they are just chunks of data.  If you want to use strings then use `std::string` instead.

Also, use an initializer list in C++ constructors, not java style

```
Book::Book(long int n, const std::string &a, int j, bool x)
    : number(n),
    author(a),
    year(j),
    lent(x)
{ }
```

Comment: Better yet, make the argument `std::string const & a` (unless you are going to move-construct `Book::author` from it).

Comment: @Ryan: I don't know if changing from char[25] to std::string is valid. It might be a problem, if the UML says "char[25]". But if it does not, using std::string is of course much better style and less error prone!

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs in your code:

```
Book::Book(long int n, const char a[25], int j, bool x)
{
    number=n;
    strncpy(author, a, 25);  // author = a;  doesn't work! shouldn't compile either...
    year=j;
    lent=x;
}
```

**First:** The variable author is a pointer to a zero terminated string. You can use strcpy() to copy this string. Therefore you need to `#include <memory.h`. But you need to be sure that the string -is- really zero-terminated and fits into your target variable! Else you'll overwrite other memory regions next to the target variable, which is also called a buffer overflow! Better use strncpy(target, source, maxlength); which avoids this problem.

**Second:** Your parameter a should be "const" as you want to be able to call it with a string constant like in `Book b1(123456, "test", 2014, false);` where `"test"` is a constant!

As others already suggested you should use `std::string` instead of `a[25]`. C-Strings are "C" and not "C++" and you should try to avoid them. C-Strings can introduce a lot of bugs into your code and enable buffer overflows (=security problems), too. Also they are more complicated to handle. You need to `#include <string>` to use them.